# Highcharts no y data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, highcharts

I cant get yAxis data in highcharts. see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/6496/
I load highcharts with below code.

```
  $(function () {
        $('#RankingReportsHistory').highcharts(
        {!! json_encode($KeywordVisibilityChart) !!}
        );
    })
```

The content of **$KeywordVisibilityChart** is in the array below, i get the array from my controller in Laravel, and I get all the dates in the xAxis but no data in yAxis in the visible chart, but the array contains both yAxis and xAxis data.

I think the problem is that yAxis array it contains double qoutes, how do i best remove them for each element.?

```
array:10 [▼
  "chart" => array:4 [▼
    "type" => "spline"
    "renderTo" => "RankingReportsHistory"
    "style" => array:2 [▼
      "fontFamily" => "open sans"
      "letter-spacing" => "0.5px"
    ]
    "backgroundColor" => "#ffffff"
  ]
  "credits" => array:1 [▼
    "enabled" => false
  ]
  "rangeSelector" => array:1 [▼
    "selected" => "1"
  ]
  "title" => array:1 [▼
    "text" => false
  ]
  "subtitle" => array:1 [▼
    "text" => false
  ]
  "xAxis" => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "datetime"
    "categories" => array:35 [▼
      0 => "14.07.2016"
      1 => "15.07.2016"
      2 => "16.07.2016"
      3 => "17.07.2016"
      4 => "18.07.2016"
      5 => "19.07.2016"
      6 => "20.07.2016"
      7 => "21.07.2016"
      8 => "22.07.2016"
      9 => "23.07.2016"
      10 => "24.07.2016"
      11 => "25.07.2016"
      12 => "26.07.2016"
      13 => "27.07.2016"
      14 => "28.07.2016"
      15 => "29.07.2016"
      16 => "31.07.2016"
      17 => "01.08.2016"
      18 => "02.08.2016"
      19 => "03.08.2016"
      20 => "04.08.2016"
      21 => "12.08.2016"
      22 => "17.08.2016"
      23 => "19.08.2016"
      24 => "21.08.2016"
      25 => "22.08.2016"
      26 => "23.08.2016"
      27 => "24.08.2016"
      28 => "25.08.2016"
      29 => "26.08.2016"
      30 => "27.08.2016"
      31 => "29.08.2016"
      32 => "30.08.2016"
      33 => "31.08.2016"
      34 => "01.09.2016"
    ]
  ]
  "yAxis" => array:1 [▼
    "labels" => array:1 [▼
      "format" => "{value:.2f}"
    ]
  ]
  "tooltip" => array:2 [▼
    "crosshairs" => true
    "shared" => true
  ]
  "plotOptions" => array:1 [▼
    "spline" => array:1 [▼
      "marker" => array:3 [▼
        "radius" => 4
        "lineColor" => "#fff"
        "lineWidth" => 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "series" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "domain.com"
      "marker" => array:3 [▼
        "enabled" => true
        "radius" => 5
        "states" => array:1 [▶]
      ]
      "shadow" => true
      "tooltip" => array:2 [▼
        "valueSuffix" => "%"
        "valueDecimals" => 2
      ]
      "data" => array:35 [▼
        0 => "12.2667"
        1 => "12.3667"
        2 => "11.8"
        3 => "11.9667"
        4 => "11.8333"
        5 => "11.9333"
        6 => "12.5333"
        7 => "12.7667"
        8 => "11.8333"
        9 => "12.9333"
        10 => "12.9"
        11 => "12.9667"
        12 => "13.2"
        13 => "13.3667"
        14 => "13.4667"
        15 => "13.4667"
        16 => "12.7333"
        17 => "13"
        18 => "12.7"
        19 => "12.7"
        20 => "12.7"
        21 => "12.1667"
        22 => "11.8667"
        23 => "11.8"
        24 => "11.6667"
        25 => "11.2"
        26 => "11.2333"
        27 => "11.3333"
        28 => "11.2333"
        29 => "11.9333"
        30 => "12.0667"
        31 => "11.6667"
        32 => "11.5667"
        33 => "11.5667"
        34 => "11.9667"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I hope that anybody here can see what the problem is, i have tried to look it trough but no luck.

Only difrence i have made to the site is that i moved it to a new webserver(vps), before i worked fine. 
I have checked if there where any file that dident get loaded, but everything loads just fine.

Please help me.! :)

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out, it was because i had double qoutes in my data that goes into yAxis.

So after i changed this code

```
$(function () {
        $('#RankingReportsHistory').highcharts(
        {!! json_encode($KeywordVisibilityChart) !!}
        );
    })
```

To this instead, everything worked :)

```
$(function () {
            $('#RankingReportsHistory').highcharts(
            {!! json_encode($KeywordVisibilityChart, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) !!}
            );
        })
```